# What does ::1 mean?

Tags: ip, ipv6

What does ::1 mean? I'm trying to find out my IP and the result is ::1.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Its the loopback address in ipv6, equal to 127.0.0.1 in ipv4.

Comment: so i am using IPv6 connection now?

Comment: your local hostname is resolving to ipv6 before ipv4.

Answer (score 21):

::1 is the compressed format [IPV6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) loopback address 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1. It is the equivalent of the IPV4 address 127.0.0.1.

If you are trying to find your machines public IP address then you can use [whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org/).

If you want to know the IP address of a network interface then you would need to tell us what operating system you are using.

Comment: I am using windows 7...

Comment: And I am having a problem on HTML 5 geolocation(the browser is having a problem getting my MAC address)...Additional details..

Comment: ipconfig is the command to use to find the IP address of a network interface in Windows 7. If you are having problems with geolocation then it is most likely the public IP address that you want.